# Restart JVM process in Linux Screens

Tags: linux, shell, jvm, gnu-screen

I have a JAR application that launches in a detached screen on machine startup (Ubuntu 14.04). The command is `screen -d -m file.sh`

This works as intended minus one caveat. When he Java process terminates, so does it's screen (as expected.)

**When stopping and restarting the JVM, what is the best way to ensure it will have a dedicated screen to run in?**

I've read into zombie processes and tried it by modifying my `.screenrc` file. This worked as explained by the article author, but the problem here is I need to press the "resurrect" key for it to actually continue. Is there a way to either automate the resurrection or, perhaps more preferably, automatically start the new JVM in a new screen- terminating the old one. Perhaps this can be done by tweaking my `file.sh` shell? Or somewhere else? Any ideas appreciated.

This Jar gets started and stopped frequently for various reasons but it should always be running (or returning to a running state) unless manually stopped by an administrator, in which case admins can just enter its screen, stop it, and start it again before detaching.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how about: don't "stop and start the jar" but stop and start a shellscript with your screen command

Comment: @StefanHegny I'll see if I can find a way to implement that, but the Jar is proprietary and is made to stop and start frequently.